# A Default Dict that default's to a dictionary with pre-generated keys

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

If there a better way to accomplish this?

```
from functool import partial
from collections import defaultdict

dict_factory = partial(dict, {'flag_name' : False,
                              'flag_name2' : False,
                              'flag_name3' : True, etc.}

self.ids_with_flags_dictionary = defaultdict(dict_factory)
```

The goal here being a dictionary of keys(the keys being id's of some kind) that autogenerates the list of default flag states if I call an ID that hasn't been called before.

Comment: What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what do you feel is wrong here?

Comment: `dict_factory = lambda: {'flag_name': False, 'flag_name2': False, …}` works the same and is a little simpler.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing code that already works.


Comment: I feel like I'm abusing the purpose of partial here, I'm not really partially declaring a function here, I'm making a declared dictionary a callable instead. The purpose of the code isn't "plainly obvious."

Comment: you don't really need the lambda or partial... `{'flag_name':False, 'flag_name2':False}.copy` would also work the same (see below answer), and is already a function with no arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it exactly, but using `partial` seems a bit overkill just to return a static value.  Why not just:

```
defaultFlags = {'flag_name' : False,
'flag_name2' : False,
'flag_name3' : False,
# etc.
}

self.ids_with_flags_dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultFlags.copy())
```

Comment: That is so much more obvious and simple than my "solution." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `lambda` with [dict.fromkeys](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
In [15]: x = collections.defaultdict(
             lambda: dict.fromkeys(
                 ['flag_name', 'flag_name2', 'flag_name3'], False))

In [16]: x['foo']
Out[16]: {'flag_name': False, 'flag_name2': False, 'flag_name3': False}
```

---

Or, to accommodate arbitrary dicts, just return the dict from the `lambda`:

```
In [17]: x = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'flag_name': False, 'flag_name2': False, 'flag_name3': False})

In [18]: x['foo']
Out[18]: {'flag_name': False, 'flag_name2': False, 'flag_name3': False}
```

Comment: Ah yes, but I failed to mention not all keys start with the default value of False. Sorry about that.